# Presto job is not working in cluster mode, Only use one node performance

Tags: presto

I have 2 node presto cluster and when I run the query it run only on one node,

----------Presto worker--------------

```
config.properties

coordinator=false
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8181
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=2GB
discovery.uri=http://10.0.0.30:8181

jvm.config

-server
-Xmx16G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

node.properties

node.environment=production
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-fffffffffffa
node.data-dir=/var/presto/data

-----------presto coordinator------------
config.properties

coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8181
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=2GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://10.0.0.30:8181

jvm.config

-server
-Xmx16G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

node.properties

node.environment=production
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
node.data-dir=/var/presto/data
```

When I run following query it use only one node,
select cdr_timestamp from smsc_cdr_2019_07_12 where origination = '0705529921';

this table have 40M records and 35 columns.

when I run the query with 1 server it will split to 17 and 3.30min took,
with both servers it will also split to 17 and also 3 min + taking

when running with 2 nodes the second node memory consumption is almost 0 for presto.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What's the connector that exposes your `cdr_timestamp` table?
BTW `#troubleshooting` channel on Presto Community slack (https://prestosql.io/community.html) is likely a better place for this kind of problems.

Comment: I'm using mysql connector

Answer (score 2):

Presto JDBC-connectors are usually single-threaded. In Presto parlance, e.g. MySQL connector creates a single split for each table accessed in a query. Thus, reading happens on single node, in a single thread.

There is a proposal to extend JDBC-based connectors to be parallel: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/389

Note: this aforementioned limitation is not inherent to JDBC connectors in general, this is simply current state of things. For example [Starburst Teradata connector supports parallel reads](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/connector/teradata.html#configuring-concurrency).